# 'optimize' not finding variables inside a function call

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following function that draws some data from a chi-squared distribution and compares the distribution of X to a known chi-squared distribution using maximum likelihood. This procedure is simulated `nSims` times. (I compare these results to results from a permutation test, but that code is excluded.)

```
chi2c <- function(xdf=2, yObs=100, xObs=100, nSims=1000, nPerm=500, alpha=0.05){
  simResults <- sapply(1:nSims, function(x){
    # Draw variables
    x  <- rchisq(xObs, df=xdf)
    # Other variables not relevant here
    # [[snip]]

    # Permutation test
    # [[snip]]

    # Calculate the statistics necessary for maximum likelihood
    n       <<- length(x)
    sumlx   <<- sum(log(x))
    sumx    <<- sum(x)
    # Calculate the maximum likelihood estimate
    dfhat   <- optimize(f=c2ll, interval=c(1, 10), maximum=TRUE)$maximum
    # Calculate the test statistic: -2 times the log likelihood ratio
    llr     <- -2 * (c2ll(2) - c2ll(dfhat))
    # Compare the test statistic to its asymptotic dist: chi-squared
    lReject <- llr > qchisq(1 - alpha, df=1)

    # Provide the results
    # [[snip]]
  })
  # Calcuate means across simulations
  rowMeans(simResults)
}
```

This function calls `c2ll`, the chi-squared likelihood function

```
c2ll <- function(dfHat){
  -n * log(gamma(dfHat/2)) - n * (dfHat/2) * log(2) + 
  (dfHat/2 - 1) * sumlx - sumx/2
}
```

This function does just what I would like and is accurate, but I don't understand why I have to set the maximum likelihood statistics (`n`, `sumlx`, and `sumx`) globally to get it to work; `optimize` doesn't find them if I only set them inside the function using `<-`. I tried setting them inside of `optimize`, but that didn't work either. Thanks for your help.

Charlie

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  It seems to be behaving as one would expect: if c2ll is defined globally, then lexical scope would demand that any variable lookups first happen in c2ll and then globally.  There would be less confusion if you defined c2ll as having all of its inputs as function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has lexical scoping, which means that functions look for variables in the environment in which they were defined. c2ll is defined in the global environment, so it doesn't see your definitions of n, sumx, and sum1x inside the function. S on the other hand uses dynamic scoping, which behaves as *you* expect (i.e. it looks for variables in the scope in which it was called). Computer scientists generally believe that dynamic scoping was a dead-end bad idea, and that lexical scoping is the way to go.

**As a practical matter, what can you do about this?**

Well, there are a couple options...

**First**, you can define your function locally:

```
n       <- length(x)
sumlx   <- sum(log(x))
sumx    <- sum(x)
c2ll <- function(dfHat){
    -n * log(gamma(dfHat/2)) - n * (dfHat/2) * log(2) + (dfHat/2 - 1) * sumlx - sumx/2
}
dfhat   <- optimize(f=c2ll, interval=c(1, 10), maximum=TRUE)$maximum
```

**Second**, you can have c2ll take additional parameters, and pass those parameters through optimize.

```
#in global env
c2ll <- function(dfHat,n,sum1x,sumx){
  -n * log(gamma(dfHat/2)) - n * (dfHat/2) * log(2) + 
  (dfHat/2 - 1) * sumlx - sumx/2
}

#...
#in function
n       <- length(x)
sumlx   <- sum(log(x))
sumx    <- sum(x)
dfhat   <- optimize(f=c2ll, interval=c(1, 10), n=n,sum1x=sum1x,sumx=sumx, maximum=TRUE)$maximum
```

Both are clean options that preserve the encapsulation of your functions.

Comment: There's an error int the last sentence of your first paragraph... dynamic twice?

Answer (score 1):

Your simResults function returns a logical vector. Rather than using rowMeans, just use mean(simResults) and the results look reasonably sensible ... at least to the extent that:

```
> chi2c(alpha=0.05)
[1] 0.057
> chi2c(alpha=0.5)
[1] 0.503
```

Comment: Thanks, DWin. Yes, the function is working fine, but I'm wondering why I need to use `<<-` to set the ML statistics in the global environment in order for `optimize` to find them, whereas, if I define them only within the function environment using `<-`, `optimize` does not find them. Seems a bit quirky and I don't really like defining variables outside the function (i.e., globally).

Comment: I recognized that there might be a scoping problem and therefor placed the c2ll function as the first line in the body of chi2c. That did not produce the expected results and my suggestion to change to mean(simResults) was the outcome of my debugging efforts from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem stems from the lexical scoping rules that R uses. See more in the [language definitions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Lexical-environment) manual. In short your function c2ll is looking for the variables in the environment it was defined.

To avoid that problem you have to pass the  n, sum1x and sum2x explicetly as arguments to your function, or define your function locally in the ch2c function directly.

This is quite a common question, there are a lot of interesting examples on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lexical+scoping+%5Br%5D).